# Test for autocorrelation

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing

I wanted to test if there's significant autocorrelation in my data.

Here's the reproducible code(R!) and the result.

It looks like that dwtest and bgtest and acf are all too much different.

Can anyone explain why?

```
x <- c(0.7925444, 0.7762130, 0.8865089, 0.7795858, 0.8452071, 0.8662722, 0.8350888,    0.8311243, 
   0.9182249, 0.8745562, 0.7926627, 0.8620710, 0.8832544, 0.8769822, 0.8554438, 0.8737870, 
   0.8660947, 0.7863314, 0.6154438, 0.6821302)

plot(x)
print(acf(x)) # autocorrelation with lag 1 is .444
r.test(n=19, r12=.444, twotailed=T) # psych, p<0.057
r.test(n=19, r12=.444, twotailed=F) # psych, p<0.028
dwtest(x~1) # lmtest, p=0.003202
bgtest(x~1, order=1) # lmtest, p=0.02548
bgtest(x~1, order=2) # lmtest, p=0.07175
bgtest(x~1, order=3) # lmtest, p=0.1422
bg1<-bgtest(x~1, order=1) # lmtest, 
bg2<-bgtest(x~1, order=2) # lmtest
bg3<-bgtest(x~1, order=3) # lmtest
coeftest(bg1)
coeftest(bg2)
coeftest(bg3)
```

---

Here's the result.

```
> print(acf(x)) # autocorrelation with lag 1 is .444

Autocorrelations of series ‘x’, by lag

     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12     13 
 1.000  0.444  0.007  0.003 -0.026 -0.162 -0.122 -0.045 -0.018 -0.066 -0.229 -0.143 -0.084 -0.127 
> r.test(n=19, r12=.444, twotailed=T) # psych, p<0.057
Correlation tests 
Call:r.test(n = 19, r12 = 0.444, twotailed = T)
Test of significance of a  correlation 
 t value 2.04    with probability < 0.057
 and confidence interval  -0.01 0.75
> r.test(n=19, r12=.444, twotailed=F) # psych, p<0.028
Correlation tests 
Call:r.test(n = 19, r12 = 0.444, twotailed = F)
Test of significance of a  correlation 
 t value 2.04    with probability < 0.028
 and confidence interval  -0.01 0.75
> dwtest(x~1) # lmtest, p=0.003202

    Durbin-Watson test

data:  x ~ 1
DW = 0.9017, p-value = 0.003202
alternative hypothesis: true autocorrelation is greater than 0

> bgtest(x~1, order=1) # lmtest, p=0.02548

    Breusch-Godfrey test for serial correlation of order up to 1

data:  x ~ 1
LM test = 4.9908, df = 1, p-value = 0.02548

> bgtest(x~1, order=2) # lmtest, p=0.07175

    Breusch-Godfrey test for serial correlation of order up to 2

data:  x ~ 1
LM test = 5.2693, df = 2, p-value = 0.07175

> bgtest(x~1, order=3) # lmtest, p=0.1422

    Breusch-Godfrey test for serial correlation of order up to 3

data:  x ~ 1
LM test = 5.4419, df = 3, p-value = 0.1422

> bg1<-bgtest(x~1, order=1) # lmtest, 
> bg2<-bgtest(x~1, order=2) # lmtest
> bg3<-bgtest(x~1, order=3) # lmtest
> coeftest(bg1)

z test of coefficients:

               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -0.0040142  0.0146745 -0.2736  0.78443  
lag(resid)_1  0.5620365  0.2297329  2.4465  0.01443 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> coeftest(bg2)

z test of coefficients:

               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -0.0003946  0.0162649 -0.0243   0.9806  
lag(resid)_1  0.5970411  0.2421936  2.4651   0.0137 *
lag(resid)_2 -0.2196302  0.3874252 -0.5669   0.5708  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> coeftest(bg3)

z test of coefficients:

               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -0.0038382  0.0184468 -0.2081   0.8352  
lag(resid)_1  0.6152723  0.2516847  2.4446   0.0145 *
lag(resid)_2 -0.2291774  0.3976063 -0.5764   0.5643  
lag(resid)_3  0.1780751  0.4088146  0.4356   0.6631  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: This looks like R code and R is likely to be  the most popular software environment among people here, but it's still good practice to flag it as R for the sake of people who don't use it or won't recognise it. (If it's not R, that simple request is further strengthened.)

Comment: It is R! I added it. Anyhow, I tried to add the output so I copied the output from the R studio and pasted it, it came out ugly so I erased it. I also consulted with Formatting Help but I cant find how to paste the output as it is... Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: I just added the p-valued output at the end of the function... see the p-value from dwtest... it's way lower than any other result and there are some inconsistency among the outputs from other function too..

Comment: If you want your output to look right, you need to indent it as a code block, by selecting it and pressing the $\{\}$ button at the top of the edit window. It should then look almost exactly as it does in your R session.

Comment: @Glen_b I am afraid it doesn't. I tried it but it looks all messed up. Especially "> " part gets weird. I see it's because ">" is reserved for some functionality here. So my question still remains. Is there any quick way to copy and paste my R output as it is?

Comment: It does, I've done it a hundred times. Put it in and someone will format it for you.

Comment: Okay, I did as you told. {} button, paste the output from my R studio. :)

Comment: Fixed. The idea was that once you paste it in, then as I said above, you (i) *select it*, (ii) *then press the {} button*. Exactly as you would a code-block. How did you format your code?

Comment: Wow, cool! I used to old-fashioned 4 spaces. Wasn't so beautiful though.